# Postfix, Exchange Online - Copy specific e-mails to another mailbox received during the night

Tags: postfix, exchangeonline

We used postfix + sieve before, but we migrated to Exchange Online, therefore we need another solution, postfix is still running as a mail gateway.

We need to copy e-mails received from a specific e-mail address (mail@example.com) with a specific subject (like "**PROBLEM") from 6pm to 8am and on saturdays/ sundays to another mailbox (problem@example.com).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find another solution: postfwd (Postfix firewall daemon).
At least when it comes down to sender and time checks, because it cannot match subject, body, etc.